# blobs indices and mask it in continuum image

Tags: idl-programming-language

I need to find blobs indices and then mask them at the continuum image.
Who can help me?
please let me know how can I list the indices of blobs.
I use blob_analyzer to analyze the images.
Cheers
Mahtab

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to have more information, but I'm assuming you are using `blob_analyzer` from the Coyote IDL Library.

So, you make a blob object from your image:

`blobs = obj_new('blob_analyzer', image)`

You can find out how many blobs were identified using the `NumberOfBlobs` method:

`n_blobs = blobs -> NumberOfBlobs()`

Alternatively, you can get summary information about all the blobs using the `ReportStats` method:

`blobs -> ReportStats`

**To get the indices for the ith blob, use the `GetIndices` method:**

`indices = blobs -> GetIndices(i)`

This should give you a 1D vector of indices, which you can convert to 2D indices using `ARRAY_INDICES`, if you want.  That would be:

`indices_2D = array_indices(image, indices)`

**To mask the blobs in the image, you can simply do:**

```
new_image = image  ;Make a copy of the original image
new_image[indices] = 0  ;Set all the pixels in the blob to 0
```

That will, of course, only mask the pixels in the ith blob, but you could simply make a loop to repeat the above process for all the blobs.

```
new_image = image ;Make a copy of the original image
;Loop through and mask blobs
for i = 0, n_blobs - 1 do begin

    indices = blobs -> GetIndices(i)  ;Get indices for the ith blob
    new_image[indices] = 0            ;Mask those pixels

endfor
```